# Como fazer um footer (rodapé) ficar fixo apos o efeito Parallax?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, front-end, layout, background

Tenho essa imagem e gostaria de ter um efeito igual a opção 3 (três) dessa imagem, segue:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

DETALHE: poderia ser a opção 2 (dois) só que não quero que o rodapé passe para a área da tela independente do conteúdo ser pequeno ou não, quero que o rodapé fique sempre abaixo da tela (nunca igual a opção 1 (um)

Comment: Define o `container` com o conteudo do corpo com `min-height:100%` assim ele vai ter no minimo 100% da tela, e o footer fora desse container, assim ele vai sempre estar abaixo da tela

Comment: OK, vou tentar.

Comment: Deu certo a dica?

Comment: Não, agora não sei se é por causa de outras propriedades que tenho na minha `<div>` (`<div class="container-fluid fundo-container">`): 

Segue o **CSS** do fundo-container: 

    .fundo-container {
        background-image: url('../../assets/img/fundo.jpg');
        background-position: center top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
       background-attachment: fixed;
       min-height: 100%
    }

Como veres já ta com a tua **ajuda**

Comment: faltou o posicionamento, tem q ser relative, os pais e filhos para o height funcionar

Comment: OK, vou tentar.

Comment: Olha não funcionou, uso o **Bootstrap 4** não sei se tem alguma interferência e mais um **detalhe**: quando uso o `height: 100vh` funciona porém *buga* o conteúdo, não fica fluído o conteúdo quando eu redimensiono a tela.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77515/discussion-between-wees-smith-and-rafael-souza-calearo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesmo usando o exemplo Oficial do Sticky Footer vc vai precisar de fazer alguns ajustes de CSS. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Esse modelo abaixo eu peguei direto na documentação do BS4 e precisei fazer uma adaptação simples de CSS para sempre deixar o footer para fora da página, para isso vc precisa colocar no `bottom:` o valor negativo referente ao valor da altura do próprio `footer`. No exemplo o `footer` tem `height:60px`, então coloquei `bottom:-60px` e deu certo. No código tem os comentários dos desenvolvedores do próprio Bootstrap e um que eu mesmo fiz pra vc saber onde setar o `bottom` negativo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <style>
    
    /* Sticky footer styles
        -------------------------------------------------- */
        html {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
        }
        body {
        /* Margin bottom by footer height */
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        }
        .footer {
        position: absolute;
        /* 60px é a altura do próprio footer, por isso usando valor negativo ele fica para fora da página a própria altura */
        bottom: -60px;
        width: 100%;
        /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }

        /* Custom page CSS
        -------------------------------------------------- */
        /* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

        body > .container {
        padding: 60px 15px 0;
        }

        .footer > .container {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        }

        code {
        font-size: 80%;
        }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body cz-shortcut-listen="true">

    <header>
      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Begin page content -->
    <main role="main" class="container" style="
    height: 380px;
    background: red;
">
      <h1 class="mt-5">Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
      <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A fixed navbar has been added with <code>padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code>body &gt; .container</code>.</p>
      <p>Back to <a href="../sticky-footer">the default sticky footer</a> minus the navbar.</p>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, vou ajustar para ver.

Comment: Ok qualquer coisa me fala. Repare que independente da altura do MAIN, o footer sempre vai estar para fora da página. E quando o MAIN for muito grande o footer vai continuar lá embaixo sem ficar por cima dos outros elementos. Nos testes que eu fiz aqui ficou 100%. Se ai não rolar vc vai ter que avaliar seu CSS para ver se não tem nada interferindo nas classes que foram usadas para funcionar... Como falei esse exemplo é o oficial e bem simples... mas funciona!

Comment: OK, vai funcionar.

Comment: @RafaelSouzaCalearo legal jovem tmj!